# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> is returning null last childtoken of the two childrentokens

Tags: asp.net, json, api, jsonconverter

I am sending a JObject from the frontend to my API, which is divided into First and Last childtokens, as seen in the picture below:

[image: The sample JObject request]

However, when I am trying to use the following code, the last part of childrendtoken is becoming null

```
var RVoucher = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VMReceive>(request.ToString());
```

This is what I am having in the debugging mode:

[image: The last child is null]

Here, the VMReceive is a viewModel that consists of another viewmodel "VMMonth"and an ado.net generated model class "ReceiveVoucher".
Code of the models are given below:

```
public class VMReceive
{
    public List<VMMonth> Month { get; set; }
    public ReceiveVoucher receiveVoucher { get; set; }
}

public class VMMonth
{
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public string item_text { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReceiveVoucher
{
    public int ReceiveVoucherId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MonthId { get; set; }
    public string ReceivedBy { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReceivedAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried putting [JsonProperty("")] over each property of my "ReceiveVoucher" model class, but got the same 'null' issue.

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong here, your suggestion regarding this will be very helpful.

Comment: `receiveVoucher` is not the same as `ReceiveAmount`...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the entire request json as text in your question. One thing I see initially is you're passing a string for ReceivedAmount when your class defines it as a Nullable<int>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON property name doesn't match. Your class uses `receiveVoucher` whereas the JSON is `ReceiveAmount`. Also, why are you using `JObject` in the first place, this should work by just using the class name as the action parameter:

```
public HttpResponse PostReceive([FromBody] VMReceive RVoucher, int userId)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG, you are a life saver, however, from now on I'd use class name as parameters in cases like this.